# How to write triggers for an update on two table one after another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, sql-update

```
Customer(cid, cname, caddress, ccity, cstate, czip, ccardnum)
Product(pid, pname, pbrand, pprice)
ShoppingCart(cartid, cid, active, totalprice)          
ShoppingCart.cid references to Customer.cid
CartItem(cartid, pid, iprice, iquantity)     
CartItem.cartid references ShoppingCart.cartid, 
CartId.pid references Product.pid
Order(oid, cartid, time, payprice) Order.cartid references to ShoppingCart.cartid
```

Create triggers that, when the price of a certain product changes, update the price of this item in any active shopping cart containing the item, and also updates the total price of these shopping carts?.

```
CREATE TRIGGER priceupdate AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE cartitem 
SET iprice=new.pprice 
WHERE pid=new.pid 
and cartid in 
(select cartid                                           
from shoppingcart WHERE active='1');

UPDATE shoppingcart 
SET totalprice = 
(select sum(iprice*iquantity) 
from cartitem WHERE cartid=new.cartid;
END;
```

Above code was givin me error because i am updating shopping cart which is used for updating cartitem 
When I tried code given below worked fine but I am not able to update total price in shoppingcart.Can Someone help me with updating shopping cart totalprice

```
CREATE TRIGGER priceupdate AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE cartitem 
SET iprice=new.pprice 
WHERE pid=new.pid and cartid in 
(select cartid                                           
from shoppingcart WHERE active='1');
END;
```

NOTE:I am using MYSQL

Sample data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8489e9/4/3

Comment: Consider to provide sample data for all relevant tables in tabular form and exact table schemas. Better yet create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER product_priceupdate 
AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE cartitem i JOIN shoppingcart c
      ON i.cartid = c.cartid
     SET i.iprice = NEW.pprice 
   WHERE i.pid = NEW.pid 
     AND c.active  = 1;

  UPDATE shoppingcart c JOIN
 (
   SELECT cartid, SUM(iprice * iquantity) totalprice
     FROM cartitem 
    WHERE cartid IN
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT i.cartid 
              FROM cartitem i JOIN shoppingcart c
                ON i.cartid = c.cartid
             WHERE i.pid = NEW.pid 
               AND c.active  = 1
          )
    GROUP BY cartid
 ) q
     ON c.cartid = q.cartid
    SET c.totalprice = q.totalprice;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd7fc1/1)** demo

Comment: thanks for your reply but unfortunately the solution which u provided is also updating shopping cart which are inactive so it wont serve the purpose.

Comment: @Shaz Sorry, it was a typo in aliases in JOIN conditions (should be `i.cartid = c.cartid` instead of `c.cartid = c.cartid`). It's fixed. See updated answer and sqlfiddle demo.